# Spark streaming Redis Read Time Out with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming, spark-redis

While i'm reading table from redis getting this below error.

Below code normally working well.

```
val readDF= spark.sparkContext.fromRedisKeyPattern(tableName,5).getHash().toDS()
```

Normally it's working for less than 2 million rows. But if i'm reading big table getting this error.

> 18/10/11 17:08:25 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 37.0 in stage 3.0
>   (TID 338) redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out   at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill(RedisInputStream.java:202)
>     at
>   redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte(RedisInputStream.java:40)
>
> val redis =
>   spark.sparkContext.fromRedisKeyPattern(tableName,100).getHash().toDS()

I also changed some settings on redis but i think it's not about that.
Do you know how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: xref: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/issues/98

Comment: This could be (but may not) due to the client's output buffer exceeding the limits - can you check the Redis server's log for a warning in the form of: "Client %s scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits."?